# EF Core - duplicate error when adding entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When adding entities to a `DbContext` in EF Core I get following error message:

`The instance of entity type 'OrderTask' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.`

Indicating I have multiple entities with the same Id (Id:1). But this is not the case.
Any suggestions on the source of this error or how to debug it would be appreciated.

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE "Tasks" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Description"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Tasks" PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

**Entity**

```
public class OrderTask : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public async Task AddOrUpdateTasks()
{
    using var cn = new SqlConnection(_cn);
    await cn.OpenAsync();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_Task_Sel_All";
    cmd.Connection = cn;

    using var dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    while (await dr.ReadAsync())
        _orderContext.Tasks.Add(new OrderTask() { Id = (int)dr["TaskNumber"], Description = (string)dr["TaskDescription"] });


    await _orderContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**Method**

```
public async Task EFWorkcenterTest()
{
    var orderContext = new OrderContext();
    orderContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    orderContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var adapter = new Adapter(orderContext);
    await adapter.AddOrUpdateTasks();
}
```

I already tried checking for duplicates with

```
var dup = _orderContext.Tasks.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
              .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
              .Select(y => y.Key)
              .ToList();
```

but this returned 0.

Explicitly setting the key also did not help.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderTask>()
        .HasKey(x => x.Id);          
}
```

Comment: My guess is `AddOrUpdateTasks` is called multiple times on the same context? So the first run is still in the cache.

Comment: When debugging the method is only hit once. Other calls with different entities work just fine.

Comment: Well we don't know what "usp_Task_Sel_All" does so it's pretty hard to help you...

Comment: @keuleJ Does this matter when it does not return duplicate ids?

Comment: Are you shure it doesn't return ID 1 every time you call it?

Comment: Put the breakpoint just before adding tasks and inspect the `_orderContext` to see if anything is being already tracked. Then check what do you have after `Tasks.Add`.

Comment: @keuleJ Yes, it does return a list with 2000+ unique entries. (Id = 0, Id = 1, Id = 5, ...)

Comment: replace `_orderContext.Tasks.Add(` with `someLocaldefinedList.Add(` and do the group by code on that.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev The `ChangeTracker.StateManager` is empty before calling `Add` the first time. Then it fills up.

Comment: @Firo This also returns an empty list.

Comment: @rosi97 aren't you adding the first records every time? The one with the id 1?

Comment: Is Id and identity column in database?

Comment: @MikeMozhaev I added the `Create Table` code to the question.

Comment: @keuleJ No, I checked the entries in a local list. The error still occurs if I do `AddRange` to the `_orderContext` afterwards.

Comment: @rosi97, seems like this column gets auto-assigned values. Will it work if you don't assign Id when adding tasks? If yes then you would probably need to either remove `AUTOINCREMENT` if you want to assign the Ids, or let the database assign them.

Comment: Try to figure out what `Id = (int)dr["TaskNumber"]` assigns.

Comment: @rosi97, please share `OrderContext` declaration.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev Removing `AUTOINCREMENT` on the table did it! Since the first entry from the `SqlCommand` returned `Id = 0`, EF Core or SQLite assigned it the value `1`. So after this point there were two duplicate entries. Thank you very much for the ida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing AUTOINCREMENT on the table did it!
Since the first entry from the SqlCommand returned Id = 0, EF Core or SQLite assigned it the value 1. So after this point there were two duplicate entries.

Thanks to @MikeMozhaev!